# Winform does not contain a definition for my method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass an image object from one winform to another with the following code.

In my first winform I have this at the top of the class:

```
 public Image SavedImage
 {
    get { return PictureBox.Image; }
    set { PictureBox.Image = value; }
 }
```

And in the initializer for my first winform I have the following code:

```
 public ControlPanel(Image savedImage)
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    _screenCapture = new ScreenCapture();
    _screenCapture.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;
    SavedImage= savedImage;
 }
```

Then in my second winform I am passing that image object back to my first winform like so:

```
 this.InstanceRef.SavedImage = savedImageObject;
 this.InstanceRef.Show();
 this.Close();
```

However when I run this code I get the following error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'SavedImage' and no extension method 'SavedImage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

As far as I can tell, this is correct code. But my compiler is telling me it isn't. How can I overcome this code?

InstanceRef relates to the following code:

```
  private Form m_InstanceRef = null;
  public Form InstanceRef
   {
      get { return m_InstanceRef; }
      set { m_InstanceRef = value; }
   }
```

Comment: What is `InstanceRef`?

Comment: Instance ref is a get and set for my form. I shall put up the code now.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you named your form class `YourFormClass` and `SavedImage` is actually defined in your `YourFormClass`:

```
((YourFormClass)this.InstanceRef).SavedImage = savedImageObject;
```

Or you can re-define your `InstanceRef` property as follow:

```
private YourFormClass m_InstanceRef = null;
public YourFormClass InstanceRef {
  get { return m_InstanceRef; }
  set { m_InstanceRef = value; }
} 
//Then you don't need to cast InstanceRef to YourFormClass
```

Comment: Hey man I actually already have that code in my project. Thank you though but the issue still persists.

Comment: As I'm using two winforms are you suggesting YourFormClass is actually my first winform? I'm confused by your naming terms.

Comment: @Sean yes, what is the class name of your first form? For example, normally we have the default names `Form1`, `Form2`, ...